# Sorting Structures

Tags: sorting, structure

Basically I need to sort arrays of structs by value from highest to lowest.
I must read from file into structure and then sort it.
Initial information:
  `6
m k 250
f k 280
m p 240
f p 290
m s 63
f s 45`

My attempt: *(sorting part might be incorrect)*

```
using namespace std;

struct clothes
{
char gender;
char type;
int price;
};

int main()
{
ifstream file("duomenys.txt");
int amount;
int end;
file >> amount;
end = amount;
clothes robe[amount];

for(int x = 0; x<amount; x++)
{
    file >> robe[x].gender >> robe[x].type >> robe[x].price;
}

for(int x = amount - 1; x>0; x--)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(robe[i].price > robe[i+1].price)
        {
            ???                
        }
    }

    end--;
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new in programming so please keep your answer as beginner-friendly as possible as I don't know much.
**How do I swap information between struct robe[0] and robe[1]** and sort them after checking if price is higher ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember the rule: when you get stuck, try something simpler. Do you know how to swap two numbers? Do you know how to copy information from one sruct to another?

Comment: Would it be correct just writing
robe[i].gender = robe[i+1].gender;

robe[i].type= robe[i+1].type;

robe[i].price = robe[i+1].price;

Comment: That's a good start. I urge you to try that -- with two structs for now (robe1, robe2), not an array -- and see what happens. Then try `robe1=robe2`. And at some point you should write a function that takes a garment as an argument and prints all the information it contains; nothing beats being able to see what you're doing.

Comment: Say I swap information from robe1 to robe2, then how do I put robe2 info into robe1,  do I have to use a holder,  if so,  how

Comment: Good question! "Swap" means exchange. You know how to copy one garment to another ({shirt, hat} -> {shirt,shirt}), and you know how to swap two numbers ({3,5} -> {5,3}) by copying. Can you combine these ideas and swap two garments ({shirt, hat}->{hat, shirt})?

Answer (score 0):

@Beta
So I came up with something that worked, I declared additional struct which I used for holding values while swapping, and then swapped each value (gender, type, price) seperately into holder seperately.

```
robeH.genderH = robe[i].gender;
robe[i].gender = robe[i+1].gender;
robe[i+1].gender = robeH.genderH;

robeH.typeH = robe[i].type;
robe[i].type = robe[i+1].type;
robe[i+1].type = robeH.typeH;

robeH.priceH = robe[i].price;
robe[i].price = robe[i+1].price;
robe[i+1].price = robeH.priceH;
```

Thanks for help
P.S. Is it good practice to do it like I did or is there better way

Comment: That's a good step. Now try `robe1=robe2` and see what happens. And don't forget to write a `print(clothes x)` function, it'll save you a lot of trouble.